# Why does this Error appear on my screen? Do i need to install something or did I forgot something to do? Newbie here

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this error what does this mean? Please help me I'm a newbie

Require stack:
Require stack:

- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\plugins.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\index.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\index.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- C:\Users\admin\tnginatlaga\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
  at Array.map ()

Answer (score 0):

try to delete your node_modules and package-lock.json, and run 'npm i'